# Differences among dependence, statistical relationship and causation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, independence, causality

From Wikipedia we can [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence):

> In statistics, **dependence** or **association** is any **statistical
>   relationship**, whether **causal** or not, between two random variables or
>   two sets of data. **Correlation** is any of a broad class of **statistical
>   relationships** involving **dependence**, though in common usage it most
>   often refers to the extent to which two variables have a linear
>   relationship with each other. Familiar examples of dependent phenomena
>   include the correlation between the physical statures of parents and
>   their offspring, and the correlation between the demand for a product
>   and its price.

They introduce some concepts: `dependence` (or association), `causality`, `correlation` and `statistical relationship`.

Ok, (linear) correlation does not imply causation and that's fine, but I do not clearly understand the differences between aforementioned concepts, introduced in that wikipedia article.

I read a lot of post on this community but I did not find a complete answer to this question.

Comment: I may have answered your question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208418/57345

Comment: @LizzieSilver I read! But Can you provide a formal definition of the four concepts that I mentioned?